# seekTo() doesn't work when playing m3u8 live stream

Tags: android, live, m3u8

Platform:Android 4.2

My video server returns all ts stream in the last two hours when i request m3u8 in live mode.
For example, now 23:00, and I want to play one hour before , I want to call `seekTo(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` method, but actually, seekTo does not work,I guess it is live stream, m3u8 return label does not contain # EXT-X-ENDLIST, so I get `getDuration() = 0`.

What should i do to let ts stream to play back in live mode?